# How can I get distinct values for the area.names using graphene?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

my resolver in schema.py looks like this

```
def resolve_areas(self, info, **kwargs):
    result = []
    dupfree = []
    user = info.context.user
    areas = BoxModel.objects.filter(client=user, active=True).values_list('area_string', flat=True)
```

In GraphiQL I am using this query:

```
{
  areas  {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And get Output that starts like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "areas": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QXJlYTpkZWZ",
            "name": "default"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QXJlYTptZXN",
            "name": "messe"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QXJlYTptZXN",
            "name": "messe"
          }
        },
```

But i want distinct values on the name variable
(Using a MySQL Database so distinct does not work)

SOLVED:

distinct was not working. so i just wrote a short loop which tracked onlye the string names duplicates in a list and only appended the whole "area" object if it's name has not been added to the duplicates list yet

```
result = []
dupl_counter = []

for area in areas:
  if area not in dupl_counter:
    dupl_counter.append(area)
    result.append(Area(name=area))
    print(area)
```

Comment: distinct was not working. so i just wrote a short loop which tracked onlye the string names duplicates in a list and only appended the whole "area" object if it's name has not been added to the duplicates list yet
result = []
    dupl_counter = []
    
    for area in areas:
      if area not in dupl_counter:
        dupl_counter.append(area)
        result.append(Area(name=area))
        print(area)